# @RequestParams for custom object types - parameter names

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Controller managed in SpringBoot defined as such.
I wanted to pass in an entire object, rather than repeating all the fields of `MyCustomObject` to save some typing.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> add(@ModelAttribute MyCustomObject myObj) { }
```

WHen testing out the request method, I'm not sure what the individual request parameter names are. I would have though it would have direclty been the field names. My naming convention is to put 'm' as a prefix.

It turns out that the request parameters that Spring decides to set, using trial and error, are without the `m`, e.g. 'chicken' rather than 'mChicken'.  I'm wondering what is controlling this. Perhaps it's using the set/get method names and just chopping off the get/set prefix there?

Also, I'm wondering if using a @ModelAttribute this way is the right thing to do. I'm not sure what someone developing a front end would do here, if they'd look at my spring controller, or something else that publishes the REST api. Perhaps it's better to have the individual parameters, rather than having a full @ModelAttribute there. But, it does save me some effort in trying to programatically create the object from the individual parameters.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_stuff")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyCustomObject{

    private String mBeef;

    private String mChicken;


    public String getBeef() {} 
    public void setBeef(String beef);

    public String getChicken() {} 
    public void setChicken(String chicken);

}
```

Is there a way in Spring Boot to see the REST API on the server (using gradlew bootRun to test manually). It would be nice to verify the actual params.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are the JavaBeans conventions, which look at the public API of your class. Your class has *properties* named `beef` and `chicken`, and the corresponding methods are `get`/`set` (or `is` in the case of booleans).

The JavaBeans convention doesn't care how you store the property--it's even quite possible for the property not to be stored at all (e.g., `isEmpty()`).

As to your larger question, `@ModelAttribute` (or `@RequestBody`) is used when the inputs are some coherent whole, such as a form. You might have a `UserRegistrationForm` with username, first/last names, e-mail address, password... Use `@RequestParam` when the parameters are more loosely related, such as the various parameters of a search.

Comment: So if you had a form and were adding a new object with multiple params, @ModelAttribute makes sense, but if you were, say, searching for something with a coulpe of loose fields, e.g. "find by name", then having them as separate Request params would make sense.

Comment: @StealthRabbi Pretty much. It's a pretty close match for the Command Object pattern, if you're familiar with that, and I frequently have `@ModelAttribute`s that are actually objects defined in service interfaces.